# Running multiple Python scripts simultaneously and then sequentially

Tags: python, bash, scripting

I can run multiple Python scripts simultaneously from a bash script like this;

```
#!/bin/bash
python pr1.py & 
python pr2.py &
python aop.py &
python loader.py &
```

But what if I want a batch to fire simultaneously and after they've run, start some more sequentially.  Will this work?:

```
#!/bin/bash
python pr1.py & 
python pr2.py &
python ap.py &
python loader.py
python cain.py
python able.py
```

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

On your bash script you can simply add the `wait` command like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
python pr1.py & 
python pr2.py &
python ap.py &
wait
python loader.py
python cain.py
python able.py
```

`wait` will, obviously, wait for all the jobs (the background proccess you fired) to be finished for it to continue.

Answer (score 50):

Once you put & at the end, it runs as a background process. Hence all the scripts ending with & run in parallel.

To run the other 3 scripts in sequential order you can try both:

`&&` runs the next script only if the preceding script has run successfully

```
python loader.py && python cain.py && python able.py
```

`||` runs scripts sequentially irrespective of the result of preceding script

```
python loader.py || python cain.py || python able.py
```

Comment: Can you accept the answer if you think it solved your problem

Answer (score 0):

With the & command you are running the scripts in the background.   you could add a check in a loop to run the command **jobs** and see if it continues to return a list of jobs.  when it stops you can continue with your next batch of python calls.

Comment: That would probably be a better alternative. I can edit my answer or you could add it Josh.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try it out ?

```
#1.py
import time
time.sleep(3)
print("First script")

#2.py
import time
time.sleep(3)
print("Second script")
```

If you put the processes into background, you will see the output from both the python scripts at the same time.

```
#!/bin/bash
python 1.py &
python 2.py &
```

If you execute it without the `&`, then you will see the output from the second script after 6 seconds.

```
#!/bin/bash
python 1.py
python 2.py
```

PS: Be careful to take care of dependencies and concurrent access issues while running it in parallel