# Running two python scripts simultaneously from batch file, using anaconda, not working

Tags: python, batch-file

So, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28549641/run-multiple-python-scripts-concurrently) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42072715/running-multiple-python-scripts-simultaneously-and-then-sequentially), to run two python scripts simultaneously I should run them from a batch file, separated by a `&`.

However, this does not seem to be working in a simple example.

I am currently trying this:

**test1.py**

```py
import time
for i in range(5):
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Printing, test1:"+str(i))
```

**test2.py**

```py
import time
for i in range(5):
    time.sleep(2)
    print("Printing, test2:"+str(i))
```

**batch file**

```
call "C:\Users\Username\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat"
"C:\Users\Username\Anaconda3\python.exe" "C:\Users\Python\Documents\Python\Test\test1.py" &
"C:\Users\Username\Anaconda3\python.exe" "C:\Users\Python\Documents\Python\Test\test2.py" &
```

I would expect to see the results mingled, however, this is the outcome:
[image: outcome3]

It is clear that script 2 is running after script 1.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Both of your linked questions are clearly talking about Unix shell scripts, *not* Windows batch files.

Comment: Wow.. I didn't pick up on that. Thanks! Any way to do it on Windows?

Comment: `&` concatenate commands in batch file, so second is run after first has finished. to run both use `start “” “first command”` `start “” “second command"`. note first pair of quotes are window title. see `start /?` for further information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @jasonharper pointing out that the two solutions I had found were specific to Unix, *not* Windows (although I had searched for Windows), I was able to find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13880650/how-to-call-run-multiple-python-scripts-from-batch-file-in-window-xp-7) other post, that *is* for Windows.

With a little adaptation to conda, I was able to get bot scritps to run simultaniously, like this:

**batch file**

```
call "C:\Users\Username\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat"
start python "C:\Users\Username\Documents\Python\Test\test1.py" &
start python "C:\Users\Username\Documents\Python\Test\test2.py" &
```

The results are pretty cool.. Two python windows running simultaneously:
[image: results2]

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Use multiprocessing or threading modules of python

```py
import time
import threading
def test1():
    for i in range(5):
        time.sleep(1)
         print("Printing, test1:"+str(i))
def test2():
    for i in range(5):
        time.sleep(2)
        print("Printing, test2:"+str(i))
x = threading.Thread(target=test1)
t = threading.Thread(target=test2)
x.start()
t.start()
```

Comment: Thanks. However, this didn't work for me. I am still getting one result after the other. I tried both, from a batch file and from PyCharm.